# JavaScript Canvas getImageData() function returning data with all the values as 0

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, getimagedata

I am trying to make a Chrome extension. I am trying to take screenshots using the video method in JavaScript, and then drawing the video frame on canvas, then getting image Data using `getImageData()`, but it's still not working it is giving data with 0 values like this:

[image]

I tried all methods on stack Overflow like using the `onload` method and others but still nothing works for me.

I am sorry the code is over commented for better understanding because I always write messy code
here is the code:

```
//A function to take screenshot
const takeSnip = async () => {
  try {
    //Creating stream to capture a single frame of the current tab video
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ preferCurrentTab: true });
    
    //Creating video element
    const video = document.createElement('video');
    
    //Creating canvas element
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    
    //Some styling to the canvas
    canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
    canvas.style.margin = 'auto';
    
    //Creating context
    const CTX = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    //Adding event listener to the video
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
      
      //Defining the width height of the canvas
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      
      //Playing the video
      video.play()
      
      //Drawing the image on the canvas
      CTX.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      
      //Stopping the video on first frame as a screenshot
      stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
      
      //Adding the canvas to the body
      document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    })
    
    //Getting image data from the drawn image on canvas
    const imageData = CTX.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    video.srcObject = stream;
    
    //Printing the imagedata on the console
    console.log(imageData.data)  //It is getting all the data with 0 values as shown above
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be getting the image data after you draw onto the canvas. Why not move the `getImageData` call inside the listener?

Comment: brother I can't tell you how much you jsut helped me I was stuck on this from 3 days thank you for your help 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `getImageData()` inside the `adddEventListener()` that would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your `loadedmetadata` event is being called asynchronously. There is no guarantee that the callback of the event will finish before you call `getImageData`.

You could wrap your event listeners in an `async` function that returns a `Promise`:

```js
const onLoadMetadataAsync = async (video) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', (event) => {
      resolve(event);
    });
  });
```

Now, you can await the event response:

```js
const event = await onLoadMetadataAsync(video);
```

Modified script:

```js
const onLoadMetadataAsync = async (video) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', (event) => {
      resolve(event);
    });
  });

//A function to take screenshot
const takeSnip = async () => {
  try {
    //Creating stream to capture a single frame of the current tab video
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ preferCurrentTab: true });
    
    //Creating video element
    const video = document.createElement('video');
    
    //Creating canvas element
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    
    //Some styling to the canvas
    canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
    canvas.style.margin = 'auto';
    
    //Creating context
    const CTX = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    //Adding event listener to the video
    const event = await onLoadMetadataAsync(video);
      
    //Defining the width height of the canvas
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;

    //Playing the video
    video.play()

    //Drawing the image on the canvas
    CTX.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //Stopping the video on first frame as a screenshot
    stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();

    //Adding the canvas to the body
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)

    
    //Getting image data from the drawn image on canvas
    const imageData = CTX.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    video.srcObject = stream;
    
    //Printing the imagedata on the console
    console.log(imageData.data)  //It is getting all the data with 0 values as shown above
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```